# Are you a bound by a contract with sorority that you signed if you have not paid dues to become an official member?

Tags: contract-law

Are you a bound by a contract with sorority that you signed, if you have not paid dues to become an official member?

Comment: It depends to some extent on when the contract says it takes effect (it may say it only takes effect upon payment of dues on its face) and upon which provision it seeks to enforce (e.g., a non-disclosure agreement might apply to non-disclosure of rush activities even if you aren't an official member). Other terms of the contract and the place it is entered into (different places have different laws) could matter as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Typically, yes

When you signed you promised to do things (follow the rules and pay your dues) and they promised to do something. That creates a legally binding contract.

Just because you are in breach of the contract because you haven’t paid, you are still legally obliged to follow the rules. Whether the sorority wants to pursue you for the unpaid dues is up to them.

If you want to end your obligations, you have to terminate the contract in accordance with its provisions. For these types of contracts, you generally can’t while you are non-financial.

Comment: I did not pay dues at all

Comment: @Princess56 yes? You’re still bound. And you owe money.